# WebpackDevServer работает только при запросах на localhost

Tags: webpack-dev-server

ОС: Windows 10

В конфиге WebpackDevServer записано следующее:

```
const WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_HOST = process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_HOST;
const webpackPort = last(WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_HOST.split(':'));
....
webpackServer.listen(webpackPort, '0.0.0.0', () => {
    console.log('Listen webpack-dev-server on ' + WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_HOST);
});
```

В переменную окружения WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_HOST записываю "http://testhost:5050"
в hosts записываю testhost как 127.0.0.1

Но почему то webpackServer работает только при обращении в браузере по localhost:5050 и 127.0.0.1:5050, если же обращаюсь по testhost:5050 то выдает Invalid Host header

Answer (score 0):

Добавление опции в конфиг: disableHostCheck: true